# Did I use the right Independent Variable for my Mediation analysis?

Tags: spss, mediation

I am currently proofreading my master's thesis, but I came across a thing I wanted to make sure I am doing right. So, for my experiment, I mainly wanted to test the effect of X on Y, but effect X has 2 types. I hypothesized a difference in main-effect between these 2 types, which I tested using two-way repeated measures ANOVA. So, X only included categorical data, and Y has a pre- and post-exposure measure.

Next, I also hypothesized a mediator M on the main effect, which I calculated using PROCESS Macro model 4. Up until now, I calculated this by computing X as an IV, post-exposure Y as a DV (and M as a mediator variable). But, since I'm not a 100% sure what the output provides me, I'm currently in doubt whether I did this right and if I shouldn't have put the pre-exposure Y as an IV and post-exposure Y as DV (since X only has categorical data).

Anyone that would like to help me out with this?